# create a list of images and text files in Python

Tags: python, list, image

I have a folder **(exp)** that has 800 images and 800 text files inside another folder **(labels)**. Each image has text file.
How to create a list that has an image and a corresponding text file?

the folder looks like this:

```
-exp
  -labels
      FrameVid2_178.txt
      Frame_1103.txt
      Frame_856.txt
      ...
      ...
  FrameVid2_178.JPG
  Frame_1103.JPG
  Frame_856.JPG
  ...
  ...
```

The list should look like this:

```
[['../exp/FrameVid2_178.JPG', 'FrameVid2_178.txt'],
 ['../exp/Frame_1103.JPG', 'Frame_1103.txt'],
 ['../exp/Frame_856.JPG', 'Frame_856.txt'],
  .....]
```

My code:

```
def __init__(self):
        self.imgs_path = "../exp/"
        file_list = glob.glob(self.imgs_path + "*")
        self.data = []     
        for class_path in file_list:
            class_name = class_path.split("/")[-1]
            for img_path in glob.glob(class_path):
                self.data.append([img_path, class_name])
        print(self.data)
        self.img_dim = (416, 416)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to create a list with image and text?!

Comment: Do you mean image files' names and text files' names?

Comment: Yes. Images files path and text files path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work, not sure where you ran into trouble, but it could use a little checking/handling (note: you could do a lot more path validation/checking too, pathlib.Path is great for that).

```
def __init__(self, img_path):
        self.imgs_path = "../exp/"
        file_list = glob.glob(self.imgs_path + "*.JPG")
        self.data = []     
        for class_path in file_list:
            class_name = class_path.split("/")[-1]
            matching_labels = list(glob.glob(class_path + "/labels/" + class_name[:-3] + "*"))
            if len(matching_labels) != 1:
                raise IOError("Matching issue", len(matching_labels))
            self.data.append([img_path, matching_labels[0].split("/")[-1])
        print(self.data)
        self.img_dim = (416, 416)
```

Comment: it returns an empty list of matching_labels.

Comment: @Samahwa yes, the function doesn't return anything, it looks like you're storing the info in the class under the "data" attribute. Also, no guarantees this is exactly right as I don't have your exact file structure, or any other info about your class.